# Trolling or naive?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, specific-question

I came across this question:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/794209/twin-prime-conjecture-resolution-by-using-a-prime-number-finding-algorithm

I cannot make my mind about this thing. On one hand, it just looks like someone has been really naive to think they can prove the twin-prime conjecture in $3$ pages, but the sheer stupidity of the thought actually makes me wonder.

Can anyone really be that naive or is this a troll (in which case a flag is in order)? What do you think?

Comment: Given extreme inexperience with formal mathematics, and a great lack of knowledge about what constitutes 'proof,' I don't think it's unreasonable that someone might think it's possible to be so clever. It's not apparent to me that this is a troll.

Comment: Never attribute to malice that which can be explained by stupidity.

Comment: There are many warning signs of crankery, and short proofs are only that: a warning. Plenty of good maths can be done in only a few pages - see [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/54775/what-is-the-shortest-ph-d-thesis).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Can anyone really be that naive?

Yes. [If your name is listed on the faculty page of a half-way decent University's math department, chances are you will get some of these types of claims](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/20674/handling-unsolicited-proofs-of-famous-mathematical-problems).

It gets worse if either (a) you are famous or (b) someone famous works (or used to work) in your department.

Comment: The last time I got unsolicited emails to my university account regarding mathematics, they were composed of discussions of frogs and links to MSE, together with threats to President Obama and Terry Tao (who was cc'ed on the emails). Sometimes crazy is a nontrivial factor too.

Comment: Or if you play dice with the universe. ;-)